# Adding subheading to navigation bar in incorrect order

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, navigation

I'm coding a navigation bar feature where scrolling down pushes the subheading of a blog post into the navigation bar between the logo and menu.

What I am mainly struggling with is the order of the logo, subheading and menu. It was working first through use of 'child[x]', and was resolving errors when it threw into a bigger issue.

This is what I have now:

```
     let navbarHeading = null;
     const navbarContent = document.querySelector('.navbar-content');
     const subHeading = document.getElementById('subheading');

    //other code
 
    window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(scrollFunction, 200));

    function scrollFunction() {
      const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
      const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
      const subHeading = document.getElementById('subheading');
      const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

      if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {

        const children = navbar.children;
    
        if (!navbarHeading) {
          navbarHeading = document.createElement('div');
          navbarHeadingText = document.createElement('span');
          navbarHeading.appendChild(navbarHeadingText);
          navbarHeading.classList.add('navbarHeading');
          if (!navbar.contains(logo)) {
            navbar.appendChild(children[0]);
          }
      
          navbar.appendChild(navbarHeading);
          navbar.appendChild(children[1])

          if (!navbar.contains(menu)) {
            navbar.appendChild(children[2]);
          }
        }
    
        // Navbar Functioning
        navbarHeading.textContent = subHeading.textContent;

      } else {
        //Other code

        if (navbarHeading) {
          navbar.removeChild(navbarHeading);
          navbarHeading = null;
        }
    
        if (!navbar.contains(menu)) {
          navbar.appendChild(menu);
        }
      }
     }
```

What I am finding is that the subheading (navbarHeading) is getting added after the menu. This isn't ideal for UX as it's not a seamless transition. It should be inbetween the logo and menu (the styling hasn't changed and is working all okay).

I have tried without conditionals for appending the menu, heading and logo, but that didn't help. Using conditionals is helping to ensure that the logo and menu return to original position when scrolled up.

I hope someone is able to help, I've been staring at it for a long while now.